# Comparing secret data without giving away source

Tags: algorithm, encryption, hash, secret-key

Issue:

Company A has secret data they don't want to give away to company B.
Company B has secret data they don't want to give away to company A.

The secret data is IP addresses on both sides.

But the two companies want to know the number of overlapping IPs they have (IP addresses that both companies have in the database).

Without using a third party I can't think of a way to solve this issue without one party compromising their secret data set.  Is there any type of hashing  algo written to solve this problem?

Comment: You can easily make MD5 hashes of the ip addresses, and compare the list of hashes. But if the companies must not be able to know which addresses match, even this is no good, because if you know what IP converts to what hash, you can see which ones are shared.

Comment: An md5 of an ipv4 address is trivial to brute force

Comment: Yeah, they can't know which ones.  That wouldn't solve the issue. thanks though.

Comment: Email them to me and I'll do it. Please also let me know the contact details for either company tyvm.

Comment: Without any "third party" - like a neutral "middle man"-application - I would say this is impossible.  You could of course encrypt etc, but what is the guarantee that one or both of the companies not is sniffing on the network trafifc?

Comment: Is it a problem that really exists or just sth. like an interview question?

Comment: You could ask on http://crypto.stackexchange.com/ and/or http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Real world problem, but I simplified the secret data in order to keep the question focused.

Comment: Does it have to be an exact answer or an approximate algorithm is enough?

Comment: Exact is what I need.  I considered a few algorithms that would match a set number of bits of each piece of data and do high probability matching.  But even those can be reverse engineered up until the number of bits used for matching.  Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: This is a field of zero-knowledge proofs and almost certainly off-topic for Stack Overflow. It is also solvable with searchable encryption in both directions.

Comment: If only an exact solution will suffice, then there are situations in which some information is *necessarily* leaked: e.g. if company A has 100 email addresses and learns that it shares 100 email addresses with company B, then it knows that B has (at least) exactly the 100 email addresses it itself has.  If instead A learns that it shares 95 email addresses with B, then it can be 95% certain that any particular one of its own email addresses is shared with B, etc.

Answer (score 1):

First I'll describe a simple but not very secure idea.  Then I'll describe a way that I think it can be easily made much more secure.  The basic idea is to have each company **send an encoding of a one-way function** to the other company.

### Sending Programs

As a warm-up, let's first suppose that one company (let's say A) develops an ordinary computer program in some language and sends it to B; B will then run it, supplying its own list of email addresses as input, and the program will report how many of them are also used by A.  At this point, B knows how many email addresses it shares with A.  Then the process can be repeated, but with the roles of A and B reversed.

### Sending SAT Instances

Implementing this program straightforwardly in a normal programming language would yield a program that is almost trivially easy to reverse-engineer.  To mitigate this, first, instead of having the program report the count directly, let's reformulate the problem as a decision problem: *Does the other company have at least k of the emails in the input?*  (This involves choosing some value k to test for; of course, if both parties agree then the whole procedure can be performed for many different values of k.  (But see the last section for possible ramifications.))  Now the program can be represented instead as a [SAT instance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability) that takes as input (some bitstring encoding of) a list of email addresses, and outputs a single bit that indicates whether k or more of them also belong to the company that created the instance.

It's computationally easy to supply inputs to a SAT instance and read off the output bit, but when the instance is large, it's (in principle) very difficult to go in "the other direction" -- that is, to find a satisfying assignment of inputs, i.e., a list of email addresses that will drive the output bit to 1: SAT being an NP-hard problem, all known exact techniques take time exponential in the problem size.

### Making it Harder with Hashing

**[EDIT: Actually there are *many* more than (n choose k) possible hashes to be ORed together, since any valid *subsequence* (with gaps allowed) in the list of email addresses that contains at least k shared ones needs to turn the output bit on.  If each email address takes at most b bits, then there are much more than 2^((n-k)b)*(n choose k) possibilities.  It's probably only feasible to sample a small fraction of them, and I don't know if unsampled ones can be somehow turned into "don't-cares"...]**

The SAT instance I propose here would certainly be very large, as it would have to be a disjunction (OR) of all (n choose k) possible allowed bitstrings.  (Let's assume that email addresses are required to be listed in some particular order, to wipe off an n-factorial factor.)  However it has a very regular structure that might make it amenable to analysis that could dramatically reduce the time required to solve it.  To get around this, all we need to do is to *require the receiver to hash the original input and supply this hash value as input instead*.  The resulting SAT instance will still look like the disjunction (OR) of (n choose k) possible valid bitstrings (which now represent hashes of lists of strings, rather than raw lists of strings) -- but, by choosing a hash size large enough and applying some [logic minimisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_minimization_for_Boolean_functions) to the resulting instance, I'm confident that any remaining telltale patterns can be removed.  (If anyone with more knowledge in the area can confirm or deny this, please edit or comment.)

### Possible Attacks

One weakness of this approach is that nothing stops the receiver from "running" (supplying inputs to) the SAT instance many times.  So, choosing k too low allows the receiver to easily isolate the email addresses shared with the sender by rerunning the SAT instance many times using different k-combinations of their own addresses, and dummy values (e.g. invalid email addresses) for the remaining input bits.  E.g. if k=2, then the receiver can simply try running all n^2 pairs of its own email addresses and invalid email addresses for the rest until a pair is found that turns the output bit on; either of these email addresses can then be paired with all remaining email addresses to detect them in linear time.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [homomorphic encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption) to carry out the computation. I imagine creating something like bitmasks on both sites, performing encryption, then performing a XOR of the result. I think [this source](http://outsourcedbits.org/2012/06/26/applying-fully-homomorphic-encryption-part-1/) points to some information on what encryption you can perform that supports XOR.

Comment: Someone will need to decrypt the result, at which point they will have the bitmask or am I missing something?

Comment: There are two options - if it is allowed that the sites know which are the common IPs they can simply decrypt the data. The solution will still be better than the naive approach. Alternatively maybe a bitcount algorithm is supported by some homomorphic encryption algorithm.

Comment: I think that the same key that gets you the "final" bit data would also get you the intermediate bit-masks as the same key can decrypt both.

Comment: I was thinking on performing the computation on a third site, providing only the final result

Comment: I don't see how performing the computation on a third site and "providing only the final result" is different from using a trusted third party.

Comment: @j_random_hacker the difference is that the third party can not possibly decrypt the data - it need not be trusted

Comment: I see, that's an advantage.  OTOH I also now see that the OP actually made no mention of "trusted".

Comment: @j_random_hacker you are right. OK - so then maybe if  homomorphic encryption is used, one of the sites(say A) can send its encrypted key along with a public key, site A can then process the **encrypted** data and send out the result back to B. Essentially this is using B as the non-trusted third party.